# Loop through parent div and hide child classes with match

Tags: jquery, css

I want to loop through each div in `pageHeadings`, and if the child div's class matches "menu_", I want to hide it. What exactly am I missing here?

```
<div id="pageHeadings">
    <div class="menu_practice">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_about">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test2</p>
    </div>
```

```
$("#pageHeadings div").each(function (index, val) {
    if($(this).attr('class').match("menu_")) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

`console.log($(this).attr('class'));` gives:

```
col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 
undefined 
col-md-1 
undefined 
menu_practice 
col-md-1 
undefined 
menu_about 
col-md-1 
undefined 
menu_contact
```

So I think it's finding them okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `[class^=menu_]`, which will find elements with classes starting with `menu_`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bhz2/)

```
$("#pageHeadings div[class^=menu_]").hide();
```

Alternatively, you could also use `$(this).is('[class^=menu_]')`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns5K5/)

```
$("#pageHeadings div").each(function (index, val) {
    if($(this).is('[class^=menu_]')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. I've asked another similar question here. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419589/slidetoggle-child-classes-of-clicked-parent