# SlideToggle child classes of clicked parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through each div in `pageHeadings`, apply click function to each div that matches "heading." Then, if I click on a heading, it will slideToggle the heading's child class.

So, if I click on `heading_about` heading, it slideToggles `menu_about` child class.

What am I missing?

```
<div id="pageHeadings">
    <div id="heading_practice">                     
        <a href="#">
           <p>Practice Areas</p>
        </a>
        <div class="menu_practice">
           <p>test</p>
           <p>test2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="heading_about">                        
        <a href="#">
           <p>About</p>
        </a>
        <div class="menu_about">
           <p>test</p>
           <p>test2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings
    $('#' + this.id).children().slideToggle("fast"); 
   //should show child class (click heading_about, it shows menu_about)
   //instead shows child class, but also toggles heading
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same technique as you did in selecting the heading part, use `$(this).find` and select the child with a class starting with 'menu':

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function() {
    $(this).find('[class^=menu]').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `#` in front of `this.id` and using a class (`slide` in this example) to target your menu:

```
$('#' + this.id + ' .slide').slideToggle("fast");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xA7zu/2/)

Comment: I don't want to slideToggle the headings. I want to slideToggle the child class

Comment: Ah fair enough, jumped because I saw an immediate issue =P. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this does what you want with different selectors. you are over complicating the problem.

```
$('#pageHeadings > div').click(function(){
    $(this).children('div').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

I recommend you have it for the link instead and add stop to prevent the animation from queueing. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptS3P/3/)

```
$('#pageHeadings > div > a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').children('div').stop(true, true).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings
    $('div', this).slideToggle("fast"); //show child class (click heading_about, it shows menu_about)
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v76Bg/)**

or this:

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings
    $(this).find('div').slideToggle("fast"); //show child class (click heading_about, it shows menu_about)
});
```

would work. By the way, you shouldn't wrap links around paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for this. 1) Why shouldn't I wrap links around `<p>`? And 2) ` $(this).find('div')` is good, but what if I want to add other divs to the parent that shouldn't be altered? How can I specify that only children with `menu_` class should be altered?

Comment: 1) It's invalid prior to HTML5 and 2) you could target it in a variety of ways using classes, jQuery selectors, etc. I just based it on your example.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this.id)` gets translated to `$("heading_about")`, which is not a valid selector.

Assuming the class of the child will be in the format of "menu_" + div's id without the word "heading" (id of "heading_about" to class "menu_about", etc.), then you could do this:

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings
    // take the parent div's id, replace "heading" with "menu" and use that as
    // the class selector for the menu.
    var childClass = this.id.replace("heading", "menu")
    $(this).find('div.' + childClass).slideToggle("fast"); //show child class (click heading_about, it shows menu_about)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nKfX/

Comment: why do I have to do `this.id.replace`?

Comment: Although it would be better for all of the hidden menu divs to use the same class (for example, `.menu`) so then you could use the selector: `$(this).find('div.menu')

Comment: @Growler, because you want to look for a div with a specific class, right, and that class is different for each menu (based on your code), with the format `menu_(part of id from the div)`.  So if id `heading_about` has a div in it with a class of `menu_about`, you have to replace the word `heading` with the word `menu` to find the div with the right class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings
    $('#' + this.id).children("[class^=menu]").slideToggle("fast"); 
});
```

[JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/QaF5n/)

or

```
$("#pageHeadings div[id^=heading]").click(function () { //apply click function to all headings     
if($('#' + this.id).children("[class^=menu]").length) {
    $('#' + this.id).children("[class^=menu]").slideToggle("fast");      
}
});
```